# Is there anything too important to "offscreen" in a comic book?

Tags: creative-writing, comics

Is there anything too important to "offscreen" in a comic book?

I just read a comic book where it looked like a character had won a fight against another character, and in the next panel, we saw the post death scene where the character was talking to his dead friends, and at the end of that scene we saw the lifeless body of the character. Is this technique often criticized? I am asking, because skipping a lot of panels could be useful if you're not very good at writing compelling characters, write good fight choreographies and draw complex panels, because you could in theory just skip them. I won't say which comic book, because it's a huge spoiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with skipping dramatic and important scenes is that it requires more (if perhaps different) skills to *suggest* what happened in those scenes.  The reader needs to know enough to follow the story and feel the events of importance, in order to be engaged.

It could be done if, for instance, the details of the death would swamp the fact that the character is dead, and the story needs to focus the afterlife.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything too important to "offscreen" in a comic book?

That's a very vague question. There are many reasons why elements of a story may remain offscreen, and no general answer can be given.

In a murder mystery, the identity of the murderer often remains offscreen. He or she is of the utmost importance for the story, and yet they are never revealed until the end. Because the story requires that mystery.

Since I haven't read your comic book, it is impossible for me to say whether the fight taking place offscreen is good or bad writing.

But let's focus on the *writing problem* that you either have or hypothesize:

> x could be useful if you're not very good at writing y

That is never a good reason for anything. If you're not good at writing something, you need to get better at it.